# TypeError: Object of type 'Redditor' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, praw

I'm working on reddit crawler and got the following error. I'm new to this subject and looking for suggestions to overcome the error

```
import praw
import json

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id= client_id, \
                     client_secret= client_secret, \
                     user_agent= user1, \
                     username= username, \
                     password= password)

def prawSubreddit(subName, lm):
    print("Collecting from /r/{}...".format(subName))
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subName)
    submissions = subreddit.top(limit=lm)
    redditData = []

    for submission in submissions:
        keys = ['Title', 'Txt', 'Author']
        func = [submission.title, submission.selftext, submission.author]
        redditData.append(dict(zip(keys,func)))

    print("Finished Collecting.")
    writeOutput("{}.txt".format(subName),redditData)
def writeOutput(fileName, data):
   `outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
    outputFile.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys = True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  prawSubreddit('opiates', 5)
```

Comment: Python is saying that the `json` library doesn't understand what a `Reddit` object is, so it can't be converted to JSON format. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) answer should help.

Comment: As a side-note: the backslashes at the ends of lines 4-7 are unnecessary. Your Python is just as valid without them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific instance, you can fix the problem by casting `submission.author` to a string with `str(submission.author)`. The `json` library can't serialize a `Redditor` object (which is what `submission.author` is), but it can serialize a string.

So, replace `func = [submission.title, submission.selftext, submission.author]` with `func = [submission.title, submission.selftext, str(submission.author)]`.